# icons missing in Odoo 14

Tags: odoo-14

in a brand new installation of Odoo 14 I have installed the "web-responsive" module (in the OCA "web" repository)

in the menu screen, a couple of icons are missing (as shown in the attached picture)

[image]

AND I am seeing these messages in the log

```
2022-12-06 10:06:39,035 4436 INFO sperim odoo.addons.base.models.ir_attachment: _read_file reading /home/me/deployment_sc/data_dir/filestore/sperim/c5/c54d3d5e2b1320083bf5378b7c195b0985fa04c1 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 789, in get
    field_cache = field_cache[record.env.cache_key(field)]
KeyError: (None,)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 970, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 793, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'res.users(2,).image_128'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 789, in get
    field_cache = field_cache[record.env.cache_key(field)]
KeyError: (None,)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 970, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 793, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'res.partner(3,).image_128'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 789, in get
    field_cache = field_cache[record.env.cache_key(field)]
KeyError: (None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 970, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 793, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(10,).datas'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 789, in get
    field_cache = field_cache[record.env.cache_key(field)]
KeyError: (None,)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 970, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 793, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(10,).raw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 105, in _file_read
    with open(full_path, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File o directory non esistente: '/home/me/deployment_sc/data_dir/filestore/sperim/c5/c54d3d5e2b1320083bf5378b7c195b0985fa04c1'
```

So, I understand a file is being searched and not found

But I don't understand why

As far as I can tell, these files are supposed to be static resources of the web-responsive module or of some other module distributed with Odoo

Why aren't they found ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading all the modules with `-u all` from terminal
Or try upgrading your 'base' module.

If your database is restored from another file, try importing your file store as well.